# Copy and update formula

Tags: merge, extract

I have a formula in a cell in an Excel file (let's say the file name is "Filename1.xls") like this: `='[Filename2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$G$2`, which places the contents of cell G2 from "Filename2.xls" in this cell.

I would like to copy this formula, so that the cell below has: `='[Filename2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$G$3` and so on. How can I get it to update automatically?

Answer (score 0):

change the formula to

```
='[Filename2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$G2
```

Basically remove the $ sign so that when you copy the formula to other cells, it automatically updates the row value from 2 to 3

If you want the same behavior for columns as well, remove the $ next to "G" so it updates the column value as well